# find без полей _id в массивах

Tags: mongoose

Есть схема

```
mongoose.Schema({
    t: Number,
    d: Number,
    n: [
        {
            b: String,
            l: Number,
        },
    ],
});
```

выполняется запрос так, чтобы в результатах были только поля явно прописанные в схеме (без _id):

```
find({}, "-_id t d n")
```

получается, что поле _id в результатах отсутствует, но только то, которое относится ко всему документу. А каждая запись в массиве n так же содержит поле _id, и они таким образом не отбрасываются.

Вопрос в том, как указать, что поле _id у записей в массиве n так же должно быть исключено из результатов.

Answer (score 0):

для массивов явно исключать поля по типу:

```
-_id
```

не требуется. Надо просто перечислить поля, которые должны быть в результате:

```
find({}, "-_id t d n.b n.l")
```